# Spring. Java. Log in and activation email

Tags: authentication, spring-security, activation

I have a "chicken egg" problem.
In application I use UserDetailsService to get User (we don't store user information in our DB, we use third party service to actually get all information).

Recently we've added account activation feature. After registration, we send an activation email to a user and if he clicks on it, we mark the User as ACTIVE and redirects him to log in page. User can login only if he has ACTIVE status. The problem is: we'll start charging user from the date he activates his account even if he never logs in. How can I (maybe using spring security) make those processes (activation and login) almost simultaneous? We don't want to charge user if he just activates his account, we want to charge him only if he has logged in (after activation). So can I actually do it somehow "user clicks activation link, login and then his status is changed to ACTIVE (but he can login only if he is ACTIVE)".

Sorry if my problem description isn't clear enough

I'll appreciate any feedback.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your requirements correctly, you'll need two different entry points (login pages) to your application:

1. One for activation (first login) for users not yet activated.
2. Another "normal" one for active users.

The problem is that the authentication logic would need to be context sensitive and be aware of which of the above pages initated the authentication. However the framework was not designed for such uncommon use-cases, so the authentication provider has no knowledge about the URL from which the login-form were actually sent.

What you need to solve is to somehow relay contextual information to an authentication provider that processes the auth request according to that information (i.e. authenticate *only non-active* users logging in from url1, and authenticate *only active* users logging in from url2). There could be hundreds of different ways to achieve this, one possible solution is to put two different authenentication filters in place that intercept auth requests sent to the two different urls. Details outlined below:

1. Create your own custom versions of the existing `WebAuthenticationDetailsSource` and `WebAuthenticationDetails` (preferably by subclassing the latter) that stores and exposes the URI of the  authentication request. (That will be the contextual information based on which the auth provider can implement its conditional logic.)
2. Configure and insert two different instances of the `UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter` in the filter chain. Set their `filterProcessesUrl` attribute to `/j_spring_security_check_active_user` and `/j_spring_security_check_nonactive_user` respectively, plus inject the above created custom `AuthenticationDetailsSource` in both of them.
3. Override `DaoAuthenticationProvider.additionalAuthenticationChecks()` in a subclass in the following way:

   - Retrieve the URI stored in the above created `WebAuthenticationDetails` object (it's accessible via `authentication.getDetails()`)
   - Assert that the user is active/non-active according to the URI, and throw an `AccountStatusException` if the asserion fails.
   - Don't forget to delegate to the superclass if the assertion succeeds.
4. Create the two different login pages mentioned at the beginning of the post, making sure that the login forms post credentials to their respective URL (`/j_spring_security_check_nonactive_user` vs. `/j_spring_security_check_active_user`).